# ESTA 90 day problem

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I am visiting Florida from UK on an ESTA and have mistakenly booked return flights 92 days after arrival.

Is there an easy trip to make to a nearby country which will allow me back to Florida and stay till the 92 days and catch these flights?

Comment: If you don't know, trips to Mexico, Canada and "nearby islands" don't reset the 90-day counter, so you'll need to travel a bit further...

Comment: Are you already in the US? If not, you can apply for a B-2 visa, which will allow the 92-day stay. It's $180, so maybe cheaper than rebooking your return flight.

Comment: @phoog Plus he won't need an ESTA for the next 10 years. The downside is, the "difficulty level" (in Terms of scrutiny) of obtaining a visa is significantly higher, and if denied for any reason, he can never enter visa-free again and will have a harder time getting a visa the next time

Comment: @Crazydre true, but for most British tourists visiting Florida, there won't be any trouble getting a visa and the risk of refusal will be vanishingly low.

Comment: @Jim, what are the conditions for modifying your return ticket with your Airline?

Comment: that's a hell of a mistake.  the simple answer is you need to (suck up the change fees and) change the return date.

Comment: it's "incredibly difficult" to get a B-2, sounds like a non-starter

Comment: Costa Rica is nice this time of year.

Comment: @JoeBlow I highly doubt that a British citizen who can afford a 92-day vacation in Florida would encounter much difficulty getting a B-2.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you made a pretty bad mistake. Firstly [you'll have to go at least as far as Guatemala](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=us&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=ai&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) to restore the clock, and secondly when returning to the US so soon after such a long visit (even if only to catch a connecting flight home) the immigration officers will highly likely assume you're trying to live in the US. And if they make that assumption, it is fully up to you to convince them otherwise, which will be hard.

Have your boarding pass/flight confirmation back home+documentation proving ties to the UK ready for this, and even then there is no guarantee. Once deemed inadmissible, you'll never get in visa-free again.

If at all possible, I would seriously re-book the flight home.

Another option would be getting a B2 visa, which usually allows for multiple entries within 10 years, with a 6-month leave being given on each entry. However, be warned that, although a granted visa would solve the problem, you will be placed under closer scrutiny by the embassy than by the CBP if travelling visa-free, and if you're ever denied a visa, you can never enter visa-free again and will have a harder time obtaining a visa in the future.

As pointed out by Dorothy, in all likelihood it'll be cheapest and easiest to just modify your ticket.

Comment: How do determine needing to go as far as Guatemala?

Comment: @PeterM Canada, Mexico and the Caribbean Islands don't restore the clock, hence Guatemala

Comment: That's a good answer and +1 but it would greatly benefit from citing some source for the countries that do or don't reset the "clock".

Comment: @mts I have yet to uncover a definitive gov't resource, all of which reference 'the Caribbean.' In US common usage that would mean the obvious Puerto Rico & US Virgin Islands, Antigua and Barbuda, Barbados, Cuba, Dominica, Dominica Republic, Guadeloupe, Martinique, Saint Barthélemy, Saint Martin (French) & Dutch Sint Maarten, Grenada, Haiti, the Honduras, Jamaica, Aruba, Curaçao, Nicaragua, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Saint Lucia Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, Trinidad and Tobago, Anguilla, British Virgin Islands, Cayman Islands, Montserrat, Lucayan Archipelago, the Bahamas, Turks and Caicos.

Comment: @Crazydre and, as others here have pointed out, short visits to Central American nations (Guatemala, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Panama, and Columbia) may raise red flags which may hinder re-entry http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/leaving-usa-to-central-america-and-coming-back-to-reset-a-90-day-vwp

Comment: @Dorothy Absolutely, but OP is in a certain situation, and Central America at least technically resets the clock, meaning at least he won't have overstayed. It could still be problematic, but that way at least the 90-day clock is dealt with

Comment: @Crazydre true, and could be an easy fix. However, the cost of the trip will be far greater than the cost of changing the return flight and a hassle on re-entry, all for two days difference. And CBP likely knows all the trips, tricks, answers, excuses.

Comment: @Dorothy https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#b_5

Comment: @MichaelHampton excellent; why don't you take my list and the US code and make it into an answer?

Comment: @Dorothy I think I've answered this question too many times already.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sure you have :-) among MANY others

Comment: @Calchas indeed, it is even possible to remain in the US for up to a year in B-2 status, but you have to be able to make a good case for it when you come in, or else apply for extension of status.